# Building a UI with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, user-interface

I need to build a UI with OpenCV for my image processing project. All of my code is ready and working. I need to know if OpenCV supports building UIs? I have searched a lot with no results.

Comment: What's the problem to show images/video in separate OpenGL window or OpenGL widget?

Comment: No.I want to build an complete application.Just like a C# Windows form application.

Comment: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: I mean complete application. Using GTK, Qt or other toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV has a minimalist UI that can be (slightly) extended if it is compiled with Qt support. See the doc [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html).
However, most projects I have worked on or seen so far tend to use OpenCV as a dependency of the application engine and build the UI using other frameworks (Qt, Cocoa...).

Comment: i agree, Qt is a good choice, i'm also developing a program using OpenCV and Qt, so far it's a superb combination